# Zenity - Selector Menu Example

Tags: linux, bash, menu, selector, zenity

im trying to make a Simple Menu with Zenity under Linux

well i try with 2 Codes , but no work at all

First :

```
#!/bin/bash
Titulo="Ejemplo De Seleccion"
Pregunta="Selecciona una opcion:"
Opciones=("A" "B" "C")

echo "$Titulo"
PS3="$Pregunta "

while opt="$(zenity --title="$Titulo" --text="$Pregunta" --list --column="Opciones" "${Opciones[@] $Versiones}")"; do

    case $opt in
    "${Opciones[0]}" ) 
        echo "Has elegido $opt, Opcion 1"
        zenity --info --text="Has elegido $opt, Opcion 1"
        ;;
    "${Opciones[1]}") 
        echo "Has elegido $opt, Opcion 2"
        zenity --info --text="Has elegido $opt, Opcion 2"
        ;;

    "${Opciones[2]}") 
        echo "Has elegido $opt, Opcion 3"
        zenity --info --text="Has elegido $opt, Opcion 3"
        ;;

    "${Opciones[-1]}") 
        zenity --error --text="Opcion Incorrecta , Intenta con otra."
        ;;
    esac

done
```

I can choise "A,B,C" but this dont show me the "zenity --info --text="Something"

Second , this was more functional , but something is missed

```
#!/bin/bash

Titulo="Instalador Manual de Wine"
Pregunta="Por Favor Elige una Opcion :"

Versiones=( 
"1.6.2"
"1.7.0"
"1.7.1"
"1.7.2"
"1.7.3"
"1.7.4"
"1.7.5"
"1.7.6"
"1.7.7"
"1.7.8"
"1.7.9"
"1.7.10"
"1.7.11"
"1.7.12"
"1.7.13"
"1.7.14"
"1.7.15"
"1.7.16"
"1.7.17"
"1.7.18"
"Salir"
)



while true; do
  Opcion="$(zenity --width 309 --height 240 --title="$Titulo" --text="$Pregunta" --list --radiolist  --column "Opcion Nª" --column="Versiones de Wine" "${Versiones[@]}" "Salir")"

      if   [ "$Opcion" = "1.6.2" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 01"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.0" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 02"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.1" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 03"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.2" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 04"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.3" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 05"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.4" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 06"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.5" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 07"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.6" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 08"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.7" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 09"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.8" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 10"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.9" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 11"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.10" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 12"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.11" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 13"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.12" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 14"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.13" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 15"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.14" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 16"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.15" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 17"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.16" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 18"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.17" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 19"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.18" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 20"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "Salir" ]; then
         exit 1
         else
                      zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion Invalida"
         fi
done
```

Okey in this , i can choise , and this gave me answer , but the follows values inside the list variables "Versiones" are not showed in the Zenity :

> 1.6.2
>   1.7.1
>   1.7.3
>   1.7.5
>   1.7.7
>   1.7.9
>   1.7.11
>   1.7.13
>   1.7.15
>   1.7.17

I think its something wrong in the line

Opcion="$(zenity --width 309 --height 240 --title="$Titulo" --text="$Pregunta" --list --radiolist  --column "Opcion Nª" --column="Versiones de Wine" "${Versiones[@]}" "Salir")"

Whats is wrong ? i wanna appear all values inside varible "Versiones" i dont understand how works "${Versiones[@]}" . i copy from another script XD.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it with the follow lines

Thank you , to the Facebook user : nicolas.carlos.106 for the fix in the code

```
#!/bin/bash

Titulo="Instalador Manual de Wine"
Pregunta="Por Favor Elige una Opcion :"

Versiones=( 
"1.6.2"
"1.7.0"
"1.7.1"
"1.7.2"
"1.7.3"
"1.7.4"
"1.7.5"
"1.7.6"
"1.7.7"
"1.7.8"
"1.7.9"
"1.7.10"
"1.7.11"
"1.7.12"
"1.7.13"
"1.7.14"
"1.7.15"
"1.7.16"
"1.7.17"
"1.7.18"
"Salir"
)
Versiones=( ${Versiones[@]/#/"FALSE "} )


while true; do
  Opcion="$(zenity --width 309 --height 240 --title="$Titulo" --text="$Pregunta" --list --radiolist  --column "Opcion Nª" --column="Versiones de Wine" "${Versiones[@]}")"

      if   [ "$Opcion" = "1.6.2" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 01"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.0" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 02"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.1" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 03"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.2" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 04"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.3" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 05"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.4" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 06"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.5" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 07"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.6" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 08"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.7" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 09"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.8" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 10"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.9" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 11"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.10" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 12"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.11" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 13"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.12" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 14"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.13" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 15"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.14" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 16"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.15" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 17"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.16" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 18"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.17" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 19"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "1.7.18" ]; then
          zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion 20"
      elif [ "$Opcion" = "Salir" ]; then
         exit 1
         else
                      zenity --info --text="Has Elegido $Opcion, Opcion Invalida"
         fi
done
```